# How to find the longest increasing subsequence without sorting?

Tags: arrays, c

I want to find the longest increasing subsequence without sorting it, and to then sum the numbers of the period, for example like :

```
12, 15, 16, 4, 7, 10, 20,25
```

- `12,15,16` is an increasing subsequence.
- `4,7,10,20` is another increasing subsequence.

but since `4,7,10,20,25` are `5` elements and `12,15,16` are `3` which is less than the `4`, the output should be the sum of the longer period which is the sum of the `5` elements, `66`.

How could such a thing be done using [c](/questions/tagged/c)?
I am new to C so this is all what I could think of.

```
#include<stdio.h>
 int main() {
 int count = 0;
 int n;
 int max = 0;
 scanf("%d", &n);
 int arr[1000];
 for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
  if(arr[i+1>arr[i])
   count++;
   if(count>max)
    max = count;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. And please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: To go with my links, please don't spam tags. If you program in C then only add the C language tag.

Comment: Don't spam tags, only tag one language. Try to think more about the problem; it's not *that* hard and you get more learning value if you figure it out yourself.

Comment: On another note, you don't initialize the array `arr`, it's contents will be *indeterminate* (look at it as garbage). A good starting point would be to actually initialize it. And to make sure that the code you show is a proper [mre], and replicates the problem you ask about and nothing more (yours won't even build).

Comment: The question made me wonder more how you are going to do it with sorting it first

Comment: Hint: you don't ever set `count` to 0 when you are traversing the array. Also don't forget to initialise `arr`.

Comment: Can you solve it with pen and paper only? If you can't, don't even start thinking of making a program solving it.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep: Well, you would not sort it by element value but by descending length of the increasing substring it is in. After such sorting, the longest increasing substring is at the beginning, so all you have to do is add it up, and you are done. Obviously.

Comment: You can keep the sum of the values in the current sequence as well as the maximum sum so far; similarly, track the start position of the current sequence and the start position of the longest sequence so far, and so on.  Remember to reset current values when you come across a downwards dip.  If the array has the values in descending order, does the first element on its own count as the start of the longest increasing sequence, which has a length of 1, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You really need *two* loops.

One that iterates through all elements. This is the "starting" index of a sequence.

Then, an inner loop that starts at one element to the right of the start. It loops to the end of the array but stops if it sees the current element is out of sequence.

After the second loop ends, the difference of these two indexes is the sequence length.

---

Here is some refactored code. It is annotated:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int arr[] = { 17, 18, 19, 5, 6, 23, 24, 25, 24, 25, 17, 18, 19 };

// show -- print a sequence
void
show(int begidx,int count,const char *tag)
{

    printf("%s: %d %d --",tag,begidx,count);

    for (;  count > 0;  --count, ++begidx)
        printf(" %d",arr[begidx]);

    printf("\n");
}

// sum -- get sum of the sequence
int
sum(int begidx,int count)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (;  count > 0;  --count, ++begidx)
        sum += arr[begidx];

    return sum;
}

int
main(void)
{

    int count = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    int maxlen = 0;
    int maxidx = -1;

    show(0,count,"ORIG");

    // loop through all possible starting points for sequence
    for (int ilhs = 0;  ilhs < count;  ++ilhs) {
        int lval = arr[ilhs];

        // loop through all numbers to the right of the starter
        // stop at the array end or when we get a number that is out of sequence
        int irhs;
        for (irhs = ilhs + 1;  irhs < count;  ++irhs) {
            int rval = arr[irhs];

            // out of sequence -- we've hit the end
            if (rval < lval)
                break;

            lval = rval;
        }

        // get length of the sequence we just saw
        int curlen = irhs - ilhs;

        // remember a larger sequence
        if (curlen > maxlen) {
            maxlen = curlen;
            maxidx = ilhs;
            show(maxidx,maxlen,"NEW");
        }
    }

    // show the maximum sequence
    show(maxidx,maxlen,"FINAL");

    // sum the sequence
    printf("SUM: %d\n",sum(maxidx,maxlen));

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the program output:

```
ORIG: 0 13 -- 17 18 19 5 6 23 24 25 24 25 17 18 19
NEW: 0 3 -- 17 18 19
NEW: 3 5 -- 5 6 23 24 25
FINAL: 3 5 -- 5 6 23 24 25
SUM: 83
```

---

**UPDATE:**

A [considerable] speedup for the above is to change:

```
for (int ilhs = 0;  ilhs < count;  ++ilhs) {
```

Into:

```
for (int ilhs = 0;  ilhs < count;  ilhs = irhs) {
```

And, move the `int irhs;` above the outer loop.

This reduces the time from O(n^2) to O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an outline of one possible algorithm that will solve it using one loop.

Building blocks:

- A variable that stores the number of elements in the longest sequence encountered so far, let's call it `longest_seq`.
- A variable that stores the sum of the longest sequence encountered so far, `longest_sum`.
- A variable for counting the length of the sequence you are currently examining, `running_seq`.
- A variable keeping the sum of the current sequence, `running_sum`.

Start by initializing:

- `longest_seq = 0`
- `longest_sum = 0`

Then initialize the running variables to handle the first element. The way the following loop is created should make it clear why.

- `running_seq = 1`
- `running_sum = arr[0]`

Now to the interesting part:

- Let an index variable, `i`, loop from `1` (not `0` as usual, we handled the first element before the loop) to the number of elements you have in `arr`, minus `1`.

  - If `arr[i]` is greater than `arr[i-1]` (the previous element), the running sequence is still going on, so

    - Increase `running_seq` by `1`.
  - else, if `arr[i]` is *not* greater than `arr[i-1]`, the running sequence is broken, so

    - Check if `running_seq` is greater than `longest_seq`. If it is:

      - Save `running_seq` and `running_sum` to `longest_seq` and `longest_sum`.
    - Reset `running_seq = 1` and `running_sum = 0`.
  - Unconditionally add `arr[i]` to `running_sum`

When the loop is done, you need to check if `running_seq` is greater than `longest_seq` again (and save the values in case it is) just in case the longest sequence happened to be at the end of the array.

The answers when this is done are in `longest_seq` and `longest_sum`.

[Demo implementation](https://godbolt.org/z/T9EbMnKdj)

---

A variant with a minor difference is to change the loop slightly with regards to the updating of `running_sum`:

- Let an index variable, `i`, loop from `1` (not `0` as usual, we handled the first element before the loop) to the number of elements you have in `arr`, minus `1`.

  - If `arr[i]` is greater than `arr[i-1]` (the previous element), the running sequence is still going on, so

    - Increase `running_seq` by `1`.
    - Add `arr[i]` to `running_sum`
  - else, if `arr[i]` is *not* greater than `arr[i-1]`, the running sequence is broken, so

    - Check if `running_seq` is greater than `longest_seq`. If it is:

      - Save `running_seq` and `running_sum` to `longest_seq` and `longest_sum`.
    - Reset `running_seq = 1` and `running_sum = arr[i]`.

[Demo implementation](https://godbolt.org/z/Y1ch3fGbM)

Comment: thanks so much Ted ! your method is simple and very much clear.

Comment: just a simple question, why do we add  running_sum += arr[i]; out of the if statement doesn't this mean that it will add the elements up even thought the condition is not satisfied?

Comment: @ryan You're welcome! Re: _"doesn't this mean that it will add the elements up even thought the condition is not satisfied?"_ - No, not since the `running_sum` is reset to `0` before that when the condition is not met. An alternative way would be [this](https://godbolt.org/z/snb4Wxj3s). Perhaps that's clearer?

Comment: Last question, why do we initialize running seq with 1 instead of zero?

Comment: @ryan It's because `running_sum` initialized with `arr[0]`, so the looping starts with one element accounted for. The same happens within the loop when `running_seq` is reset. It's reset to `1` because the `running_sum` will include `arr[i]` when the iteration is done

Comment: @ryan I added a variant of the algorithm to the answer. It's a minor difference but perhaps makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: thank you that was a very simple and smart way to handle such a problem. I am a beginner in coding and sometimes I find it difficult to think of solving such problems, plus I'm not that smart so I sometimes say  I shoould just give it up. So my question is if coding really only for smart people?  and if not then how to really manage to learn solving problems with coding in a smart and logical way?

Comment: Also I find it a bit difficult understanding arrays and nested loops. Could you recommend some sites or YouTube channels that could provide some help. Thank you again !

Comment: @ryan C is not a very easy language and many of us (me included) have struggled for many years to reach some level of feeling comfortable with it. As long as you find it interesting/fun, keep at it. You'll eventually see patterns in the tasks/problems you're facing and remember how you've solved similar things in the past and can reuse that knowledge - and then you'll start picking up speed.

Comment: Since you're new to it, you are facing two problems,:the language itself and the problem you're trying to solve. When you're starting to feel a bit more comfortable with the language, it'll also be easier to rule out ideas for how to solve problems that may be cumbersome in the language and see the possible paths ahead more clearly. It's practice, practice, practice - for all of us. Unfortunately, the few YouTube videos on programming I've seen have not been worth mentioning. There are probably good ones out there, but I haven't looked for them.